# Notification alert messages for HTML

Tags: jquery, html, forms, notifications

Just wondering if anybody knows any tutorials or scripts where I can get form notifications.

Pretty much what I want is when someone types in particular keywords in a form then it needs to come up with a message.

What I want to do is when a viewer types in the following keywords into a form;

```
Medlab Central 
Medlab Wanganui 
Naylor Lawrence 
Doughboys Bakery Limited – owners surname ‘Funke’ 
Denver Stockfeeds Limited – owners surname ‘Currie’ 
Midland Civil Limited – Miles and Vicky Worsley 
Arran Trust – Stephen and Mary Barr 
Roadmarking Services Limited – Karen and Kelly halligan 
Steeds Pharmacy Ltd
```

I want a notification to popup saying 'There may be a conflict of interest. Please wait to hear from Proa regarding how they can help'

---

Had a quick go, is this the correct coding for HTML;

```
<form id="theForm">
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send Email">
</form>
</body>

<script>
var specialWords = ["hello", "goodbye"];
$(function(){
    $('#theForm').on("change keyup", "input[type='text']", function(event){
        var inputValue = $(this).val();
        if($.inArray(inputValue, specialWords) > -1){
            alert(inputValue + " is a special word!");
        }
    });
});
</script>
</html>
```

---

I have found a script that works..

```
<script language="JavaScript">
var nav=navigator.appName;
var ns=(nav.indexOf("Netscape")!=-1);

if(ns){
if(document.layers){
document.captureEvents(Event.KEYPRESS);
document.onkeypress = cheat;
}
if(document.getElementById){
document.onkeypress = cheat;
}
}
else
{document.onkeypress = cheat;}

var SpecialWords = "here"
var SpecialLetter = 0;
var vcheat = false
function cheat(keyStroke)
{
 var eventChooser = (ns)?keyStroke.which: event.keyCode;
 var which = String.fromCharCode(eventChooser).toLowerCase();
 if(which == SpecialWord.charAt(SpecialLetter)){
   SpecialLetter++;
   if (SpecialLetter == SpecialWord.length) alert("There may be a conflict of interest. Please wait to hear from PROA regarding how they can help")
}
else {SpecialLetter = 0;vcheat = false}

}
</script>
```

however I now need it to work for multiple specialwords. I tried to do what Mark said which was

```
var specialWords = ["hello", "goodbye"];
```

but wouldnt work . any suggestions.

Comment: Please clearly define your problem. What message do you want to come up with? and what are you trying to do?

Comment: Can't you just use the jquery code above (from my answer) and change the value that get alerted and the `specialWords` array?  The code below doesn't seem to add anything - and in fact it won't work in some cases - e.g. the user right-click pastes something in, or there are two input boxes etc.

Answer (score 1):

As you have tagged jquery i would assume a plugin like jquery validate

http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/validate

Demo is included at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1):

A good resource on the standard Javascript pop-ups is: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp.  Some people don't like them because you can't apply custom styling to them and are synchronous (the browser can't do anything until the pop-up is removed) but they are simple to use and do get the users attention!

I'm not sure exactly what what you want, but the following example code might be of help - it triggers an alert when the user types "hello" or "goodbye" into a text field (just change the values in the array as required!).  Here I'm assuming the mark up contains the following:

```
<form id="theForm">
    <input type="text" />
</form>
```

Then the following jquery code should do it:

```
var specialWords = ["hello", "goodbye"];
$(function(){
    $('#theForm').on("change keyup", "input[type='text']", function(event){
        var inputValue = $(this).val();
        if($.inArray(inputValue, specialWords) > -1){
            alert("There may be a conflict of interest...");
        }
    });
});
```

**Edit**: note that jquery's `on` function is as of version 1.7, if you're using an older version, try looking at [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).